Json isn't Deserializing
I'm using System.Text.Json.
I have the following models:
public  class Contacts
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("paused")]
    public bool Paused { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("owner")]
    public bool Owner {  get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("notification_targets")]
    public NotificationTargets? NotificationTargets { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("teams")]
    public List<Teams>? Teams { get; set; }
}
public class NotificationTargets
{
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public List<Email>? Email {  get; set; }
}
public class Email
{
    [JsonPropertyName("severity")]
    public string Severity { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
public class Teams
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName ("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

My Json is:
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": 14960844,
            "name": "firstname test",
            "paused": false,
            "type": "user",
            "owner": true,
            "notification_targets": {
                "email": [
                    {
                        "severity": "HIGH",
                        "address": "firstname@test.co.uk"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "teams": [
                {
                    "id": 804736,
                    "name": "Team 1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

The above is stored in a string variable.
And I just call:
var myContacts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Contacts>>(myJsonString);

and I keep receiving the following error:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted
to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VTMShared.Models.Contacts]. Path:
$ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.'

I really cannot see what is wrong with this.

Your JSON is not array, but is an object. You need the root class

You are trying to deserialize the JSON directly into a List<Contacts>,  but the JSON structure is actually an object that contains a contacts property, which holds the array of contacts.

You need to deserialize as the Root and extract the Contacts from the Root instance.
var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
var contacts = root.Contacts;

public class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyName("contacts")]
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public  class Contact
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("paused")]
    public bool Paused { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("owner")]
    public bool Owner {  get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("notification_targets")]
    public NotificationTargets? NotificationTargets { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("teams")]
    public List<Teams>? Teams { get; set; }
}

Without defining the Root class, you can work with JsonDocument:
var root = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
var contacts = root.RootElement.GetProperty("contacts").Deserialize<List<Contact>>();


You can use another Root class to deserialize whole JSON, but also you could try doing it without root - then this could be parsed to dictionary with one item:
var myContactsDict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Contacts>>>(myJsonString);

var myContacts = myContactsDict["contacts"];

